# How to set the value of input in readonly mode

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The picture below is the text field I want to edit.

[image: This is the input field.]

Now, when i try to do the following:

```
c7 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='root']/div[@id='wrapper']/div[1]/div[@class='navbar-index']/div[@class='navbar-flex']/div[2]/div[@class='left-flex']/div[@class='modal-background-withmodal']/div[@class='modal-body']/div[@class='modal-container']/div[@class='modal-content']/div[@class='add-opportunity-modal-form']/div[@class='form-main-flex'][3]/div[@class='form-field-50'][2]/div[@class='form-input-field']/span[@class='ant-calendar-picker']/div/input[@class='ant-calendar-picker-input ant-input']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'Mar 31, 2019';", c7)
```

It doesn't change the value of the input, because it is in readonly format.

```
<input readonly="" value="Mar 27, 2019" placeholder="Select date" class="ant-calendar-picker-input ant-input">
```

^ This is the code for the input element. When you click this element, it opens up a calender and shows the dates, but I do not want to go through the hassle of clicking the date. I just want to change the value of the input. Is there a way I can do it?

[image]

Comment: This looks like an antd component (https://ant.design/) which has its own state (and possibly side effects like saving the selected value in the application state). I do not recommend you changing the value directly in the DOM as it might not be recognized by the application and the form will be sent with a wrong value. Instead you should either ask your developers to provide functions to update the state outside of the application or click on the date (I would prefer the last option)

Comment: To me trying to execute JavaScript or something to alter that readonly input is way more involved than just clicking the date.  And changing the DOM directly is just not what Selenium is meant to do, instead it tries to emulate a *user’s* interaction with the browser which is entirely through the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won’t be hard to just click the button for the date you want. Should just be

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(“//input[@value = ‘Mar 31, 2019’]”).click()
```

I don’t think changing the value of that readonly input element would achieve much except maybe break the web page a bit.

Answer (score 1):

you can "cheat" a bit to achieve the typing goal.

Remove the readonly attribute.

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('ant-calendar-picker-input')[0].removeAttribute('readonly'));
```

And do the typing:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".ant-calendar-picker-input").send_keys("Mar 31, 2019");
```